# MySQL if row exists update else insert

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a site where people can sign up for events + an activity assigned to that event. They can choose which one they want to attend, or even both.

For that I made a table named "eventCounter"
[Image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMcjB.jpg)
userID, eventID and activityID are all FK poiting to other tables.

They should be able to update their current "status", so they can join the activity after they signed up for the event.

So my question is: How can I make a **If else** saying if row exists update else insert

```html
IF EXISTS(select userID, eventID, activityID from eventCounter where userID=1 and eventID=1)
THEN 
UPDATE eventcounter SET activityID=1 WHERE userID=1; 
ELSE 
INSERT INTO eventcounter (userID, activityID) VALUES(1,1)
```

I don't think the ON DUPLICATE key will work as I have 2 columns that needs to be checked?

Comment: Can't you make composite PK?

Comment: How would that help me? They are all FK's pointing to other tables (Updated topic). Even tho eventID might be 4 activityID could be 2. It's not guaranteed that an event is having an acitivty assigned.

Comment: You are doing something wrong. You want check existence by specified 2 fields, but insert different fields.

Comment: It was just an example, I know it's wrong.

Answer (score 7):

That's what is called an `Upsert`. The MySQL syntax is pretty weird, but you can do it, something like:

```
INSERT INTO eventcounter (userID, eventID, activityID) VALUES(1,1,1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  activityID = VALUES(activityID)
```

It only works for duplicate PKs though (not for any field you like), so in this case it would only work if `userID` and `eventID` compose the PK and you only want to change the `activityID`

Otherwise, you could go the IF-ELSE route, something like:

```
DECLARE mycount INT;
SET mycount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM eventcounter WHERE userID=1 AND eventID=1);
IF mycount > 0 THEN
  UPDATE eventcounter SET activityID=1 WHERE userID=1 AND eventID=1;
ELSE
  INSERT INTO eventcounter (userID, eventID, activityID) VALUES(1,1,1);
END IF;
```

Disclaimer: totally untested code

Comment: But the table eventCounter was made to be used for all events and activities, so the ID's can't be PK's or "unique". And the thing is I have 2 columns that can be changed/inserted both eventID and activityID.

Comment: Seems like I'm about to have a solution after messing a bit with your edit - the only problem is the IF syntax imgur.com/uMfV75G any idea?

Comment: I don't think an IF statement works like that outside a stored procedure or function in MySQL

Answer (score 3):

#### As 2021, things changed! So i'm updating the old `@Jcl`'s answer:

One thing you have to bear in mind is that this statement only works if a duplication occurs either to `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE INDEX` in case of inserting (**so not only `PK` but `index` also works**)!

---

**`SQL command:`**

```sql
INSERT INTO fooTable (RowNum, name, lastname, userID, score) VALUES(3,'Michael','Widenius','1012141618',19.75)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = 'Allan', lastname = 'Larsson', userNum = '2022242628', score = 10.50;
```

---

**Note:**

- **The use of `VALUES()` to refer to the new row and columns is deprecated [(Reference)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)**
- Command tested on latest `MYSQL 8.0` and `PHP Mysqli` too.
- Command above is only to show you, **how to update multiple rows**; in a real world situation, mostly you don't need to update all `name`, `lastname` and `userID` in case that record is already exist and `score` would be enough!

---

I found it pretty straight and easy to perform, you can check duplication on almost every important field in your case (using **`UNIQUE INDEX`s**)! **just remember the very first line...**

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if anyone looking for a single query statement without any extra process to create an array to set the values, can try this query method. This is just an improvement over `@Shahaboddin's` answer.

```
INSERT INTO eventcounter 
    (
    userID,
    activityID
    )
SELECT userID, activityID FROM eventCounter WHERE userID=1 and eventID=1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    userID = VALUES(userID),
    activityID = VALUES(activityID);
```

Note:

- Tested on MySQL 5.6