# How to update a non-unique column if row exists else update a different row in [MySQL]?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, if-statement, sql-update

I am trying to construct a query to `UPDATE` a row if it exists else update a different row. I only wish to update one row each time the query is executed. The second `WHERE` is for the case when there is no return from the first part of the query.

I wish to update a single attribute that has a default value of `'null'`. There isn't a means to use a public key as I've seen in other posts ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327128/mysql-if-row-exists-update-else-insert)).

I can return the desired tuple with a `UNION` but am then unable to convert the expression to an `UPDATE` query, as desired:

```
(SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE (foo BETWEEN x-c AND x+c) AND (bar ..) AND column='null' LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table 
  WHERE column='null' LIMIT 1)
LIMIT 1;
```

This seems to always return the first `WHERE` if exists else the second `WHERE`.

I've been receiving syntax errors when trying to design an IF-ELSE based on a count variable:

```
SET @count=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table 
              WHERE (foo BETWEEN x-c AND x+c) AND (bar ..) AND column='null' LIMIT 1);
IF @count THEN
  (UPDATE table SET column='foobar'
  WHERE (foo BETWEEN x-c AND x+c) AND (bar ..) AND column='null' LIMIT 1);
ELSE
  (UPDATE table SET column='foobar'
  WHERE column='null' LIMIT 1);
END IF;
```

I've also tried to structure a subquery but had no luck in getting the desired behaviour.

I am concerned that using a count could lead to an opportunity for race conditions? I am unsure whether there is a better approach, however.

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Comment: If the only concern are race conditions, why don't you just structure all of this within a Stored Procedure, and make it a transaction? You will need to set the transaction isolation level to (probably) READ-COMMITTED, and add `FOR UPDATE` if you need the rows locked.

Comment: Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-transaction.html

Comment: @Chosun, thanks for this. I would like to allow for concurrent updates to the table but prevent attempts to update the same row. In previous examples, I've seen the whole table locked; this would not be an acceptable bottleneck.

Comment: No problem; good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can just use `order by` and `limit`:

```
update table
    set . . . 
    where column = 'null'
    order by ((foo) AND (bar)) desc
    limit 1;
```

The `desc` will put the rows that match the two conditions first.  It will then be followed by other rows.  The `limit` chooses the first match.

I think I would be more inclined to order the two conditions separately:

```
order by (foo) desc, (bar) desc
```

Comment: Thanks for this! However, my `WHERE` conditions are ranges (`foo between x-c and x+c`). All rows have foo, bar, etc populated and there will be worst case rows higher and lower than best case. So will this still be applicable? *I've updated the question accordingly.*

Comment: Thanks for the added info. All working as desired. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? I can't promise it's fast:

```
update <table>
where
    column is null and <foo> and <bar>
    or not (<foo> and <bar>) and not exists (
        select 1 from <table> where column is null and <foo> and <bar>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. Run the first UPDATE. After this runs, the function `ROW_COUNT()` will return either 0 or 1, depending on whether the first UPDATE affected any rows.

In the second UPDATE, make the change a no-op by setting column=column if `ROW_COUNT()` indicates that the first UPDATE did change something.

```
UPDATE table SET column='foobar' WHERE (foo) AND (bar) AND column='null' LIMIT 1;
UPDATE table SET column=IF(ROW_COUNT()=1,column,'foobar') WHERE column='null' LIMIT 1;
```

However, note that ROW_COUNT() returns 0 if the first UPDATE matched rows, but didn't make any net change, because the rows it found already had the value 'foobar'.

Comment: Hi, this approach seems to update the first row with `column='null'`. I think I could be misunderstanding something? I would like to update based on all of the `WHERE` conditions else take any row with `column='null'`. Thanks!